# Can not insert null object on One to One relation Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Premise: I have searched for a long time and often found this error, however I have not yet been able to figure it out.

I've greatly simplified two simple entities. The first can exist without the second, the second can exist only if the first exists.

table_a (ID, DESC)

table_b (ID, DESC, TABLE_A_ID)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
@Data
public class TableA implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 575831681784335067L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

        @Column(name = "DESC")
    private boolean desc;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="TABLE_A_ID")
    private TableA tableA;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
@Data
public class TableB implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 575831681784335067L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

        @Column(name = "DESC")
    private boolean desc;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private TableA tableA;
}
```

I'm trying to perform a JPA insert of only table A in any case I get:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Entity must not be null

```
{
"id": 1,
"desc": "test",
"tableB": null
}
```

or

```
{
"id": 1,
"desc": "test"
}
```

everything goes well instead with

```
{
"id": 1,
"desc": "test",
"tableB": {
    "id": 1,
    "desc": "test2"
    }
}
```